# Computing the YTD using the PARTITION BY clause

Tags: oracle

I've the following dataset:

[image]

I need to compute the YTD Revenue for each combination of sender_country, receiver_country. That is for example, I should get for Canada-Nigeria 5.08 for the year 2016 and 10.24 for 2017 (if i'm not wrong). I've tried to apply the following:

```
SELECT sender_country, receiver_country, date_move, revenue, SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY sender_country, receiver_country ORDER BY date_move) as YTD FROM (TABLE));
```

However, I'm getting the following result:

[image]

As you can see I'm aggregating the results for each pair of sender_country and receiver_country but I don't manage to "reset" the aggregated revenue for each year.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add year(date_move) to your partition by

Comment: SQL Server and Oracle are two entirely different RDBMSs, with vastly different functionality and syntax. As it's highly unlikely that you're using both at the same time, one of the tags you've used does not apply. Tag spamming (using tags that are not actually relevant to your post) is frowned upon here, and is a way to get your question closed quickly. Please [edit] to remove the tag that does not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the year to the partition with either `TRUNC(date_move, 'YY')` or `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_move)`:

```sql
SELECT sender_country,
       receiver_country,
       date_move,
       revenue,
       SUM(revenue) OVER (
         PARTITION BY sender_country, receiver_country, TRUNC(date_move, 'YY')
         ORDER BY date_move
       ) AS YTD
FROM   table_name;
```